# Magento marketplace extension submission issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, marketplace

Magento marketplace is rejecting my module giving the reason but I do not know how to overcome this issue I tested EQP everything but did not find the error please suggest if anyone has solved this.

Issue :-

[image]

Comment: Have you contact them again?

Comment: @Manish have you fixed this issue ?

Comment: I am getting same issue while upload extension on marketplace

Comment: Hi @DharmendraJadav I have added my answer.

Comment: You can remove cache from block class if required.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred if xml file has cacheable="false" exist.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link src="Namespace_Modulename::js/cart-promotions.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Namesapce\Modulename\Block\Class" name="test" template="test.phtml" cacheable="false" after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer> 
</body>
```

Your composer.json file also support php [ 7.1 ]

```
{
  "name": "namespace/modulename",
  "description": "Description module in Magento2",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.22|~5.6.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "DJ",
      "email": "info@namespace.com"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "namespace\\modulename\\": ""
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have no any cacheable="false" in my xml

Comment: Still facing issue

Comment: Please check you composer.json file.

Comment: Hi @DharmendraJadav please inform me if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Could you please give me composer.json

Comment: Still i have facing same issue

Comment: I have added composer.json here!

Comment: Yupp i have same composer.json still getting same error bro